# Win32_Battery.EstimatedRunTime

Tags: battery-life, windows-rt, wmi

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the field EstimatedRunTime of the Win32_Battery WMI class is an

> Estimate in minutes of the time to battery charge depletion under the
>   present load conditions if the utility power is off, or lost and
>   remains off, or a laptop is disconnected from a power source.

However, on my Windows RT tablet the value of the field is 71582788.

I am guessing that my battery is not good for 71582788 minutes. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same value on my Dell laptop. I can only **guess**, that this is the default value when the battery doesn't support reporting the correct time.

Comment: Sounds realistic. Let's see if anybody knows a better answer, and I'll accept this one in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a probable Microsoft bug involving the overflow of a 32-bit integer value. Note that 71582788 = int[(2^32) / 60]; `EstimatedRunTime` is attempting to store a value in seconds into an unsigned 32-bit int which "rolls over" beyond 4,294,967,295.
This can be interpreted to mean "indefinite" in this context, since the discharge rate of a charging battery (connected to AC power) is theoretically zero. SInce Microsoft doesn't handle this condition very gracefully, you'll have to do it yourself:

```
if ($BatteryRunTime -eq [Math]::Round([Math]::Pow(2,32) / 60))
{
    $BatteryRunTimeText = ""
}
else
{
    $BatteryRunTimeText = "(" + $BatteryRunTime + " minutes runtime)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value 71582788 is equivalent to 0x04444444, which means the battery is beeing charged. Disconnect the Laptop from power will give you the estimated run time.